# Table with 100% width with equal size columns

Tags: html, css

I have to dynamically create a table with a variable number of columns, determined at runtime.

Can somebody tell me if it's possible to have a html table with equal size columns that are fully stretched?

Comment: And doesnt rely on you having an exact content like the first answer.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
<table width="400px">
  <tr>
  <td width="100px"></td>
  <td width="100px"></td>
  <td width="100px"></td>
  <td width="100px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For variable number of columns use %

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td width="(100/x)%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

where 'x' is number of columns

Comment: +1 for second approach. But 400 what, feet? Inches? Centimeters? Pixel? Use units. :)

Comment: That is exactly the point. The first example is indifferent to the unit used.

Comment: Does this take into account the borders of tr and tds? I suppose not.

Comment: I was wrong.. I just tried that out.. it worked.. I have td borders for 32 columns.

Comment: This approach uses deprecated attributes.  I have not tested it, but a better alternative would be to use <td style="width:100%"></td> or better yet, use a style sheet which sets .td { width:100% }.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055299/how-do-you-make-a-100-width-table-with-the-columns-all-equal-width?rq=1 where an interesting answer was placed.

Comment: For the second approach, you don't have to do it for every row. I have a header row `thead` and I just specified on the `th` cells and it works just fine.

Comment: `This attribute defines the width of the table. Use the CSS width property instead.` - Reported deprecated by Mozilla.

Answer (score 276):

If you don't know how many columns you are going to have, the declaration

`table-layout: fixed`

along with ***not* setting any column widths**,
would imply that browsers divide the total width evenly - no matter what.

*That can also be the problem with this approach, if you use this, you should also consider how overflow is to be handled.*

Comment: I would like to take this approach for a full screen table without overflow. how many columns would it create? can you please set up a demo to understand it better?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5babcvg4/ You create a table with as many columns as you want, then add the declaration to the table.

Comment: Note that table width must be set (e.g. `width: 100%;`).

Answer (score 10):

ALL YOU HAVE TO DO:

HTML:

```
<table id="my-table"><tr>
<td> CELL 1 With a lot of text in it</td>
<td> CELL 2 </td>
<td> CELL 3 </td>
<td> CELL 4 With a lot of text in it </td>
<td> CELL 5 </td>
</tr></table>
```

CSS:

```css
#my-table{width:100%;} /*or whatever width you want*/
#my-table td{width:2000px;} /*something big*/
```

if you have `th` you need to set it too like this:

```css
#my-table th{width:2000px;}
```

Comment: this does not work for me. can you provide a working example?

Comment: works now - I've tried the `td { width: 100% }` approach before and that didn't work, but `2000px` works well.

Comment: This is the best answer, even if the way HTML/CSS works is heinous.

Comment: This won't work if you have `very_long_words`, or if your row contains the `<pre>Some long text</pre>`. From all answer here, only orszaczky's `table-layout: fixed` worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Just add  `style="table-layout: fixed ; width: 100%;"` inside `<table>` tag and also if you do not specify any styles and add just `style=" width: 100%;"` inside `<table>` You will be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 5):

```
table {
    width: 100%;

    th, td {
        width: 1%;
    }
}
```

*SCSS syntax*