# How do you make a 100% width table with the columns all equal width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table that stretches 100% of the page (or whatever container it's in, depending on where I use it).

When I specify the width of the table to 100%, it automatically resizes the columns based on the width of their content. This is nice most of the time when I wouldn't mind different width columns, but for this, I need all of the columns to be the same width. I know that I could specify a percentage width for the columns, but I need this to work for any number of columns.

Here's my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/zwWHZ/2/

Is it possible to have a table with a width of 100% and equal column widths *without* having to specify the percent for each column with pure CSS?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I tried putting `table-layout: fixed;` into the `table` section of the CSS, and that appeared to work (even when I changed the number of columns).  The source where I found that is [here](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/37020).

Comment: In order for this to work every time in different contexts, you should also specify width:100% on the table itself. Otherwise, works great!